# problemas com web service Jquery + VRaptor 4 "status of 404"

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, vraptor

Eu sei q diz q não foi encontrada, mas não consigo achar onde errei.

Meu controller:

```
@Controller
public class ProdutoController {

    @Inject
    private Result result;

    @Path("/")
    public ArrayList<Produto> inicio(){
        ArrayList<Produto> listaProduto = null;
        try {
            listaProduto = new ProdutoDao().listaProduto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return listaProduto;
    }

    @Path("/teste")
    public void teste(){
        result.include("mens", "alguma coisa");
    }
}
```

Meu jquery:

```
function clicar(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<c:url value="/teste" />',
        dataType: 'string',
        success: function(retorno){
            alert(retorno);
        }
    });
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que fiz de errado?

Comment: Já usou Vraptor alguma vez ou é a primeira vez?

Comment: Estou aprendendo vraptor, ou seja é a primeira vez, preciso mapear o método do controler de forma diferente para chamar com jquery?

Comment: Eu não utilizo jquery e sim angular, mas eu colocos os verbos http em cada mapeamento. Ex: `@Get
 @Path("/colaborador)
 public void listarTodos() {...`

Comment: Tenta colocar um `@get` em cima do seu método e veja se funciona, veja no console se a requisição é feita também.

Comment: Mesmo com a anotação @Get ainda não funcionou, no navegador exibiu o erro: "http://localhost:8080/vraptorTest/teste 404 not found" logo o jquery Fez a requisição.

Comment: Tenta isso: `url: '<c:url value="/produto/teste" />',`

Comment: Eu até tentei, mas não funcionou, não configurei mapeamento para a classe, somente os métodos.

Comment: Então tente configurar, pois dessa forma como está como o front irá saber qual método chamar?

Comment: Criei uma jsp para o método teste, só pra testar a chamada e chamei a url pelo navegador e funcionou, msm sem mapear como "produto/teste"